# Prevent USB from sleeping during standby

Tags: linux, dual-boot, hard-disk

I use popOS (19.04) on an external SSD in a dual-boot setup on my windows laptop. Since the SSD is connected over a SATA-to-USB cable, I can't send my laptop to sleep/standby when I am on linux. Is there a way to tell popOS not to turn of my USB ports when in standby?